# How to return Type T in interface in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0, interface

I have an interface like this:

```
public interface IUser{
    //some properties here

    T ToDerived(User u);
}
```

I'm new to interface development, so here's what I'm trying to accomplish. I will have a base class

```
public class User
```

that does NOT implement the above interface. Then I will have a derived class

```
SalesUser : User, IUser
{
    //no properties needed because they exist in the User class

    SalesUser ToDerived(User u)
    {
        //code for converting a base User to a derived SalesUser
    }
}
```

I would like to write the function for ToDerived(User u) in the SalesUser class, but in the interface, I do not know how to define this as the ToDerived method declaration that I have now in the interface is not compiling.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx) is a link to a blog of Eric's that 's relevant to this question.  It includes both an example that looks much like the answer below, and also pitfalls of using this design mechanism.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
public interface IUser<T> where T : User
{
    //some properties here

    T ToDerived(User u);
}

SalesUser : User, IUser<SalesUser>
{
    //no properties needed because they exist in the User class

    SalesUser ToDerived(User u)
    {
        //code for converting a base User to a derived SalesUser
    }
}
```

Not sure this is what you want, but I added a generic type constraint on the interface to ensure that the generic type is `User` or inherits from it.

Comment: Beat me to it, but I would add `where T : User`.

Comment: @JimSchubert - I considered it and added while you were commenting ;)

Comment: @JimSchubert - Not trying to compete, honest

Comment: I'm not sure I like this design. The method ToDerived should be static, because you don't (AFAWK) need an existing SalesUser in order to convert a User to a SalesUser, so it would make much more sense to call SalesUser.ToDerived(myUser) than to call the same thing as an instance method. But, static members don't satisfy an interface definition. That tells me that an interface defining this method isn't necessary in the first place; you should instead make the SalesUser constructor accept a User, or simply make the method static so that it can be used without a preexisting instance.

Comment: Downvoter was me - at the time, the post was just code with no explanation of how this would solve the problem. It's still a bit light on explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by Oded solves the compilation problem, allowing you to define the ToDerived method that satisfies the interface. However, as I stated in the comment, I'm not exactly sure this is the best implementation.

The main problem I have with it is that conversion methods like this are normally needed in a static context. You don't have an instance of a SalesUser; you want one, and have a User, so you call the method in static context (`SalesUser.ToDerived(myUser)`) and you get a SalesUser (the method would be more appropriately named FromUser() or similar). The method you specify in the interface requires you to already have a SalesUser in order to convert a User to a SalesUser. The only situation I can think of in which you really would need a pre-existing SalesUser is for a "partial clone"; you are making a new SalesUser instance using information from both the User passed in and from the SalesUser on which you are calling the method. In all other cases, you either don't need a SalesUser (conversions, which should be static as mentioned), or you don't need a User (a "clone" or "deep copy" method that produces a new instance with the same data as the instance on which you called the method).

Also, consumers of your class have to know that they must call ToDerived() in order to perform the conversion from a User to a SalesUser. Normally, a C# programmer would expect an explicit or implicit conversion to be available:

```
public class SalesUser
{

    public static explicit operator (User user)
    {
        //perform conversion of User to SalesUser
    }

}

//the above operator permits the following:
mySalesUser = (SalesUser)myUser;
```

... OR, failing a conversion operator, one would expect to be able to construct a SalesUser using a User:

```
public class SalesUser:IUser
{
   public SalesUser(User user)
   {
      //initialize this instance using the User object
   }
}

//the above allows you to do this:
mySalesUser = new SalesUser(myUser);

//and it also allows the definition of a method like this,
//which requires the generic to be an IUser and also requires a constructor with a User
public void DoSomethingWithIUser<T>(User myUser) where T:IUser, new(User)
{ 
    //...which would allow you to perform the "conversion" by creating a T:
    var myT = new T(myUser);
}
```

Now, static members do not satisfy interface definitions, and interfaces cannot define static members or constructor signatures. This tells me that the IUser interface should not try to define the conversion method; instead, methods that need an IUser of some sort can simply specify that, and the user can provide an implementation as necessary without the implementation needing to know it can convert to itself.

Comment: You're right, Oded did solve the issue and answered my question in the exact way that I was looking for. However, I like your explanation on this and why I should not use this design pattern as this particular method would typically be a static method (which I agree with).

When I try to build your example, however, please keep in mind that I need the SalesUser class to inherit the base User class.

    public class SalesUser : User, IUser

So, when I try to do this, your explicit method does not work.

"user-defined conversions to or from a base class are not allowed."

Comment: Yeah, the constructor-based version is the route that opted to take for now. Will try to figure out the other way though for allowing an explicit conversion from base User to derived SalesUser. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Remember an interface defines a class and its members without providing any implementation, yo can create an interface but the interface must have the implementing class.

Comment: How is this answering the question?

Comment: I would like to write the function for ToDerived(User u) in the SalesUser class, but in the interface, I do not know how to define this as the ToDerived method declaration, I don't know if I wrong.